# To let the user check/unchecked the checkbox using keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML page where I have few checkboxes which look Iike radio buttons, i want the user to be able to check/uncheck the checkboxes using the keyboard?what should I include to achieve this functionality, I have been using aria attributes in my code but still not able to achieve it!

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Saisree - Check using enter key, space bar, both, or other?

Comment: once the element has focus (tab to it) you can use spacebar to check it or uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for any key pressed. You may want to add checking a specfic keycode on the event:

```js
$(function(){
  $('[type=checkbox]').keypress(function(e){
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('focused').focus();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="focused">Hit space
```